# Powershell: non-terminating error become terminating error if raised inside a `try` block

Tags: powershell-5.0

I need some pointer to understand this behavior:

```
'---------------------------------'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

function Do-Something {
    Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.notexistanthost.xyz/notexistantpath/'
    'first error is non-terminating'

    try
    {
        Invoke-WebRequest 'http://www.notexistanthost.xyz/notexistantpath/'
        'never reached'
    }
    catch
    {
        'second time the same error becomes terminating and go in catch block'
    }

}

Do-Something
```

A function that usually return a non-terminating error, with the same parameters return generate a terminating error when inside a `try` block.

Why and when this happens?
Is this something related to every function?

Answer (score 0):

If it works inside a try/catch, it's a terminating error.  It's lesser known, but there are 2 kinds of terminating errors, script terminating and command terminating.  The try sees the command terminating error and acts on it.  '1/0' is also command terminating.

```
try { 1/0; 'hi' } catch { 'caught' } 

caught
```

"Cannot find path" is not a terminating error:

```
try { dir foo } catch { 'caught' } 

Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path '/Users/js/foo' because it does not exist.
```